# Where can I find details on the control surfaces of the F-15C?

Tags: control-surfaces, f-15

Me and my team were working on a short animation and I need precise details on the following if you guys can point me to a website or answer them here it'll save hours off my search cause Google isn't helping much.

- The different stages of the flap extension with their degree of rotation.
- The maximum degree of the ailerons going both ways
- The maximum degree of rudder both ways
- The maximum the elevators can go both ways

And as a big bonus can you provide me with the landing gear specs as in how long it takes to extend, retract, open the great doors and so on? Or a video of an *actual* F-15C retracting and extending would be great. Not one of those mini-prototypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aileron: +/- 20 degs

Horz. tail: 26 deg up, 15 deg down

Rudder: +/- 30 degs

See: https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/87906main_H-1073.pdf

Comment: What about the flaps?

Comment: @ReubenX believe flaps are 0 to 30 degrees, but not 100% sure.